# XCode6 beta 6 Swift Compiler Error

Tags: swift, push-notification, parse-platform, xcode6, xcode6-beta6

I started to watch a YouTube Swift tutorial from user Brian Advent, in specific this tutorial about Remote Push Notification using Parse https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__zMnlsfwj4 .
After downloading the sample app and opening it on Xcode 6 beta 6 the compiler shows one error in the code below:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo:NSDictionary!) {

        var notification:NSDictionary = userInfo.objectForKey("aps") as NSDictionary

        if (notification.objectForKey("content-available") != nil){
            if notification.objectForKey("content-available").isEqualToNumber(1){
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("reloadTimeline", object: nil)
            }
        }else{
            PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
        }
```

The error is in this line below inside AppDelegate.swift

```
if notification.objectForKey("content-available").isEqualToNumber(1){
```

And the message showed is **'AnyObject?' does not have a member named 'isEqualToNumber'**

Any tip/help on how to fix this ? I would be thankfu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objectForKey()` returns an *optional* `AnyObject?`, so you have to unwrap
it explicitly with `!` :

```
if notification.objectForKey("content-available")!.isEqualToNumber(1) { ...
```

Alternatively, use an optional assignment. If combined with an optional cast (`as?`) you can
even use the fact that `NSNumber` is automatically bridged to native number types:

```
if let contentAvailable = notification.objectForKey("content-available") as? NSNumber {
    if contentAvailable == 1 {
       // ...
    }
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Could you take a look below in the new errors I got trying o fix those first ones above